# How can I modify my script to adding each line to an ArrayLList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, ontology

this is my code and I need to add each line of my file.txt to an ArrayList which I will annoted later by using  an ontotlogy (ontology has been loaded in the script) so it works when I try simple phrases such as :

//ar.add(" military  attack");

But when I want to use line from file, I am hurting a wall? pLEASE COULD YOU 
GUIDE ME

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClass; 
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom; 
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.SimpleIRIMapper;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/*
 * @author ekelodjo
 */
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static String getWord(String annotation)
    { 

        int index = annotation.indexOf("*");

        return annotation.substring(0,index); 

    }

        public static String getConcept(String annotation)
    { 

        int index = annotation.indexOf("*");
        int lIndex = annotation.lastIndexOf("*");             
        return annotation.substring(index+1, lIndex); 

    }

      public static String getType(String annotation)
    { 
        int index = annotation.lastIndexOf("*");             
        return annotation.substring(index+1, annotation.length()); 

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //lecture de fichier 

            int compteur = 0;
            BufferedReader br;
            String line;

            try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new 
            File("D:/ekelodjo/OntoTest/CorpusTexte.txt")));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("line :"+line);
            compteur++;
            }
            br.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
            }     
            // Test annotator class 
            Annot annot = new Annot(); 
            annot.loadOnto("D:/ekelodjo/OntoTest/2EME_ONTO.owl");
            //annot.loadOnto("D:/ekelodjo/OntoTest/Test1.owl"); 
            //Annot annot =  new Annot();

            OWLOntology onto = annot.getOnto();   
            //OWLOntology onto2 = annot2.getOnto();  
            ArrayList<String> ar= new ArrayList<String>(24);

            //ar.add("vehicle");
            //ar.add("military");
            //ar.add(" Vehicles autos person bus car1");
            //ar.add("car car1 vehicle military civilian person");
            //ar.add("possibly car1 vehicle military civilian person");
            //ar.add("vehicle military civilian person");
            //ar.add(" military  attack");
            //ar.add("normally ");
            //ar.add("Although Nothing Yet but");


            ar.add(line);
            ArrayList<String> list = annot.getAnnot(ar, onto);
            System.out.println("liste des annotations :" +list.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String ann = (String) list.get(i);
             String word = getWord(ann);
            String concept = getConcept(ann);
            String type = getType(ann);
            System.out.println("word = " +word);
            System.out.println("concept = " +concept);
            System.out.println("type = " +type);
            System.out.println("  ");
            }                          
            }
            }
```

Comment: "... I am hurting [hitting] a wall?"  is a terrible description of a problem. What specifically is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Poor wall... ;(

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tries many ways to add the line of my file.txt to my arrayList sothat i can use it to annote it later

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to load the text file into your `ArrayList` object, you have almost done it, just move the `ArrayList ar` definition before your `try/catch` block and add the line in your `while` loop when you read it.

Also move `br.close` to a `finally` block

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:/ekelodjo/OntoTest/CorpusTexte.txt")));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        ar.add(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "D:/ekelodjo/OntoTest/CorpusTexte.txt")));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("line :" + line);
            ar.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```